# How to setup OpenSearch in Magento 2 instead of Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to use OpenSearch instead of ElasticSearch in Magento 2

I didn't find anything to configure the OS configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Install opensearch 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

curl -o- https://artifacts.opensearch.org/publickeys/opensearch.pgp | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://artifacts.opensearch.org/releases/bundle/opensearch/2.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opensearch-2.x.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt list -a opensearch

sudo apt -y install opensearch=2.5.0

sudo systemctl enable opensearch

sudo systemctl start opensearch

## Check opensearch port.

curl -X GET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure

curl -X GET https://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v -u 'admin:admin' --insecure

Answer (score 3):

Steps to Migrate from Elasticsearch to OpenSearch **2.4.5 or below**

Go to **Magento Admin** then,

`Stores > Configurations > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search`

You can add your configurations as below:

**Search Engine** : `ElasticSearch 7`

**Elasticsearch Server Hostname** : `OpenSearch Server Hostname`

**Elasticsearch Server Port** : `OpenSearch Server Port`

**Elasticsearch Index Prefix** : `OpenSearch Index Prefix`

**Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth** : `OpenSearch Auth if enabled`

**For your reference:**

[image]

You can check the compatibility of **OS and Magento versions by** [CLICK HERE](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html)

**As per Adobe Commerce attached below:**

[image]

**NOTE:** Test Connection and run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

for Opensearch 2.5 its OK yes, what about opensearch version 1 for magento 2.4.4 and 2.4.5?

I could not find proper installtion method for Ubuntu 20.04.
Anyone has a step by step instruction even for Docker?

Comment: If you have a follow on question, please ask a new question.