# Is Elastic Search still require after move to Open Search

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.6, opensearch

I have a project and we want to use OpenSearch for  upgrade version  2.4.6 then we still need to use Elastic search. The question is coming here because Magento also uses Elastic for the category page in the lower version.

**Question:**

Still, need to use Elastic even openSearch use for 2.4.6 on the category page?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/363166/31910

Comment: No bro, i dont get answer

Answer (score 2):

No, since you use OpenSearch you don't need to use Elasticsearch anymore.

The config for the search engine for Catalog is located in Stores > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Engine (config path `catalog/search/engine`).

If you take a look at the OpenSearch module
[vendor/magento/module-open-search/etc/di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.6/app/code/Magento/OpenSearch/etc/di.xml#L18), you can see several configs to allow
Magento uses OpenSearch as the search engine for the catalog:

```
<!-- Configuration: Catalog Search / Search Engine -->
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="engines" xsi:type="array">
            <item sortOrder="40" name="opensearch" xsi:type="string">OpenSearch</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- Product-Category Data -->
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\CategoryFieldsProviderProxy">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="categoryFieldsProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="object">Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\CategoryFieldsProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapperProxy">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="productFieldMappers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="object">Magento\OpenSearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- Resolver -->
<type name="Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\Client\ClientResolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="clientFactories" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="string">\Magento\OpenSearch\Model\Client\OpenSearchFactory</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="clientOptions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Config</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Client\ClientFactoryProxy">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="clientFactories" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="object">Magento\OpenSearch\Model\Client\OpenSearchFactory</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- Index -->
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandlerFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="string">Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructureFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="structures" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearch" xsi:type="string">Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructure</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="responseErrorExceptionList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="opensearchMissing404" xsi:type="string">OpenSearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

P/S: I'm running a Magento 2.4.6 instance with OpenSearch without Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this, I think  this might help you:

https://www.yireo.com/blog/2023-04-03-elasticsearch-vs-opensearch-in-magento

https://www.nexcess.net/help/opensearch-vs-elasticsearch-for-magento-2-stores/